# How to read a text file only if it is modified?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a text file in my program. But I want to read that file only when my text file is changed.

If text file is not changed than I do not want to read that again. I tried something but I will read my text file after every 3 sec.

```
def load():
  f = open('input.txt', 'r')
  file = f.read()
  f.close()
  print(file)
  file = int(file)
  print file
  Timer(3,load).start()
load()
```

Comment: What about using the last modified file property?

Comment: how can i do that sir ?

Comment: Check last modified time : os.path.getctime(path_to_file)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

filename = "input.txt"
obj = os.stat(filename)
print("modified time: {}".format(obj.st_mtime))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-built Python libraries to achieve the same.

Building upon your existing code:

```
import time
import os.path
mod_time = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('input.txt'))
def load():
    global mod_time
    new_mtime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('input.txt'))
    if new_mtime != mod_time:
        mod_time = new_mtime
        f = open('input.txt', 'r')
        file = f.read()
        f.close()
        print(file)
        file = int(file)
        print file
    Timer(3,load).start()
load()
```

If you notice, `mod_time` ultimately keeps track of the changing modification time of the `input.txt` file you wish to read.

Comment: what is new_ctim here?!

Comment: Oops. My bad. I meant to add it as `new_mtime` instead. Will edit the post now.